# Flurl: GetJsonListAsync returns list of dynamic objects

Tags: dynamic, .net-core, casting, flurl

I am new to .NET Core and trying to figure things out; practising how to consume APIs with Flurl.
With this endpoint https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts which returns JSON array, I tried the following code, but the list consisted of dynamics which I was unable to convert. Can anyone advise how to cast the dynamic into a proper post object?

```
public class PostsApiClient
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<PostInput>> GetPosts()
    {
        var response = await "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts".GetJsonListAsync();
        IEnumerable<Post> listOfPosts = response.Select(post => new Post
        {
            Title = post.Title,
            Body = post.Body
        });
        return listOfPosts;
    }

public class Post
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetJsonListAsync` was specifically designed to return a list of dynamics. There isn't a typed (generic) equivalent specifically for lists, but all you need to do is provide a collection type to `GetJsonAsync`. In your case, this should work:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> GetPosts()
{
    return await url.GetJsonAsync<Post[]>();
}
```